# How to delete some information from a file and write again on the same file the remaining information?

Tags: python-3.x

I got the information from a file to delete some of them that the user want to delete it and I made small code to do this but when I am trying to write the information it is printed as a list

```
def removingStudent() :
    myFile = open("data.txt") # the original file
    List =  myFile.read().split()
    ask = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    del List[ask: ask + 7]
    print(List)
    myFile.close()
    myFile = open("data.txt", "w")
    myFile.write(f"{List[:]}") # I want write it like old information not like list
removingStudent()
```

Comment: Since you're splitting by spaces you need to glue it back with spaces: `" ".join(List)`. All `str` objects have join method

Answer (score 0):

Updated: use a list item for one line. `lines` is list of lines. The rewrite to data.txt while skipping `ask` line.

```
def removingStudent():

    with open("data.txt") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    
    ask = int(input("Enter a number: "))

    with open("data.txt", "w") as f:
        count = 1
        for line in lines:
            if count != ask:                  
                f.write(line)
            count += 1
            
removingStudent()
```

Comment: Thanks but still a little problem, the old information was Shown like this formatting
201955230 Fahad Ali 2 25 25 38
but now it is shown like this:
202035682
Fahad
Ali
2
25
25
38
even though I used \t instead \n but it did not work.  how can I make it like the old information?

Comment: Sorry I was missing something. Updated. Hope this work.

Comment: Sorry, it does not work :), Do you have a way to contact you?

Comment: To make it clear, there is a file that contain some information of students: id, name, absences, midterm grade, classwork grade, final grade. Each student's information located on one line. the removingStudent() function ask the user to enter an id number and convert to an index by using index method, then bring the information from the file as a list. after that writing the remaining information as a string on the file. I hope it is more clear now

Comment: Please write properly the input, desired output and error-output-now by editing your question. And I think your question on your comment above has changed from the first one.